# Removing two children and its parent with Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, onclick

Been struggling with this one I have the following DOM Structure:

```
<ol id="add_images">
    <li>
        <input type="file" /><input type="button" name="removeButton" />
    </li>

    <li>
       <input type="file" /><input type="button" name="removeButton" />
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="file" /><input type="button" name="removeButton" />
    </li>
```

Basically I'm trying to remove all children and the containing parent (the li tag) when clicking the remove button.

I have tried every manner of parentNode and removeChild combinations. With the below javascript, I can only get to the children but not the parent.

```
function addFile(addFileButton) {
    var form = document.getElementById('add_images');
    var li = form.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));

    //add additional input fields should the user want to upload additional images.    
    var f = li.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    f.className="input";
    f.type="file";
    f.name="files[]";

    //add a remove field button should the user change their mind
    var rb = li.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    rb.type="button";
    rb.value="Remove File";
    rb.onclick = function () {//This is where the problem is
        li.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        li.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

I'm sure its something simple. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to remove the `<li>`, you need to do it from its parentNode, the `ol`.

```
li.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

---

You could also use the `form` variable that is already a reference to the `ol`.

```
form.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

or:

```
form.removeChild(li);
```

---

Or you could do it all without the variables in order to avoid creating a closure.

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

Comment: hrmm, never thought of it that way. I was looking at it from the least common denominator. ie; start at the remove button and work my way up the dom. I'll remember that for next time.